# Using new to allocate an array of class elements with an overloaded constructor in C++

Tags: c++, constructor, new-operator

As an example say I have a class foo that does not have a default constructor but one that looks like this

```
foo:foo(int _varA,int _varB)
{
   m_VarA = _varA;
   m_VarB = _varB;
}
```

How would I allocate an array of these.

I seem to remember trying somthing like this unsuccessfully.

```
foo* MyArray = new foo[100](25,14).
```

I don't think this will work either.

```
foo* MyArray = new foo[100](25,14)
```

Can this be done? I typically do this by writing the default constructor using some preset values for _varA and _varB. Then adding a function to reset _varA and _varB for each element but that will not work for this case.

Thanks  for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are to be able to allocate an array of a class (directly, using `new[]`), the class must have a default constructor.  No default constructor, no dynamic arrays.

Answer (score 5):

Your first choice should be to ignore the fact that `new[]` even exists, and use an `std::vector` instead:

```
std::vector<foo> MyArray(100, foo(25,14));
```

Comment: Great advice.  Why worry about all the details to get placement new right when you can use a known working and tested implementation?